# Why is the polar representation for lines $x \cos\theta + y \sin \theta = d$?

Tags: geometry

I'm looking for a great intuitive view/explanation for seeing that this equation
$$x \cos (\theta) + y \sin (\theta) = d$$
for a given distance to the line $d$ and angle $\theta$, is a line.
I.e. points $(x, y)$ on the line satisfy it.

Basically, $d$ and $\theta$ specify the vector pointing to the line:
[image]

Comment: What we call a polar representation of the line $l $ that interests you is rather $M=(r\cos\alpha, r\sin \alpha)\in l \iff r=\frac {d}{\cos(\alpha-\beta)}$. You should rephrase your question more simply. What is xy-plane? What is a line in that plane ?

Comment: For a given angle, you have equation $ax+by=d$ which is ? Also, $-\frac{a}{b}$ would be the slope (i.e. tangent) of that line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be easily understand if you know a little of the geometry of vectors:

Given a unitary vector $u$ and a vector $v$, the projection of $v$ over $u$ has (signed) length $v\cdot u$.

In the case of $\Bbb R^2$, if you take a unitary vector $u = (\cos(\theta),\sin(\theta))$ and any other vector $v=(x,y)$, the equation $x\cos(\theta) + y \sin(\theta) = d$ can be written as $v\cdot u = d$.

This means that you are describing the points in the line as those which projection over $u$ has length $d$.

Comment: Nice, I think I get it.
So, let me phrase in my own words:
We are looking for those points (x, y) that, if perpendicularly projected onto the vector $u=(\cos\theta, \sin\theta)$, will have a projection of length $d$.
That is what the equation $x\cos\theta + y \sin \theta = d$ is saying (assuming knowledge of how dot product works, then this seems very intuitive).

Comment: @Krampfmeister Yes, that's it. If you find this answer your question you could accept my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You've represented the xy-plane, and a straight line of that plane. It is ok.

On the other hand- and this is the meaning of my comment in the comments-it is not because there is an angle and a length on your drawing, that your question is related to polar coordinates.

It is therefore necessary to clarify things by starting by specifying in which mathematical object we are going to work in order to try to answer the question asked.

You're talking about $(x,y)$ points. So you seem to know the Euclidean plane So we're going to work into that and recall that a line $l$ is a part of this plane defined by $$\boxed{l=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R| \color{red}ax+\color{blue}by=\color{green}c\}}$$where $a,b,c \in \mathbb R$.

It is a line which is parallel to the line $l_0$ passing through $(0,0)$ defined by $$l_0=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R| \color{red}ax+\color{blue}by=0\}$$

Let us now introduce vector $\vec u=(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)$. You want $\vec u$ to be a normal vector to  your line $l$, i.e you want your line to be parallel to $$l_0=\{M=(x,y)|\langle \vec {OM},\vec u\rangle=0\}$$where $\langle.,.\rangle :((x,y),(x',y'))\mapsto xx'+yy'$ designates the dot product that you certainly know.
$$l_0=\{(x,y)|\langle (x,y),(\cos \theta,\sin \theta)\rangle=0\}$$ $$l_0=\{(x,y)|\langle \color{red}{\cos\theta} x+\color{blue}{\sin\theta} y=0\}$$
We're almost there. All you have to do is impose on your line $l\parallel l_0$  that it passes through $(d\cos \theta, d\sin \theta)$ to check that the $\color{green}c$ you're looking for is $$\color{green}{c=d}$$
[image]
Heuristically, we start by looking for a line $l_0$ parallel to the line $l$ we are looking for, and passing through $(0,0)$. And so we find $\color{red}a$ and $\color{blue}b$ and then we just have to determine $\color{darkgreen}c$ and here check that it's $d$.

Comment: I don't understand the last step, how to go from $l_0$ to $l$?

Comment: $(d\cos \theta, d\sin \theta)\in l \iff \color{red}{\cos \theta}\times d\cos \theta+\color{blue}{\sin \theta}\times d\sin\theta=\color{green}c$. So, $\color{green}c= d(\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta )=d$ since $\cos^2 \theta+\sin^2 \theta =1$

Comment: @Krampfmeister : did you get it ?

Comment: Yea thanks, make sense!
But I must say, I don't like that we have to calculate $c$ instead of seeing it directly (like in the other answer by jjagmath).
I guess this comes from that you're first introducing the line condition $ax+by=c$ "out of nowhere" and it's not as clear to me how to read from that condition directly how the corresponding line looks like. Anyway, good to know this.